# Can I get a go and last card when opponent is out of cards in cribbage?

Tags: cribbage

My opponent runs out of cards during pegging, I have 3 left, can I get a go and then last card?

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely!

The [**American Cribbage Congress** *- Rule 7. The Play*](http://www.cribbage.org/NewSite/rules/rule8.asp) clearly states.

> **Rule 7.2 Scoring**
>
> *8 b.*
>
> When a player's opponent has no more cards or calls "go," the other player may play all playable cards in succession and announce the points scored before pegging the total at one time.

So yes, after your opponent runs out of cards you shall play our all your remaining cards, in any order you desire, scoring all points thereby accrued.